# How do I get output in a Perl process started from Win32::Process?

Tags: windows, perl, winapi

I have a Perl script that launches another Perl script in a new console through [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process) as follows:

```
Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
                      "C:\\Perl\\bin\\perl.exe",
                      "$path_to_other_perl_script",
                      0,
                      NEW_CONSOLE,
                      ".");

$ProcessObj->Suspend();
$ProcessObj->Resume();
$ProcessObj->Wait(0);
```

The problem is, there is no stdout in the new console created. If I don't use the new console option, the script runs silently in the background.

If I use cmd.exe to launch the Perl script, I can see the output fine but now I cannot control the child Perl script through Win32::Process.

Does anyone have a solution that works?

Comment: I use Win32::Process to spawn lots of perl processes and find that logging using Log4perl preferable over writing to the console output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your comments, I get the feeling that your programs are not examples of best practices on Linux or Windows. However, I am sure, when reading the documentation for `Win32::Process`, you noticed that you can call the `Kill` method on the process to terminate it. So, I changed the example below to do that.

Your chances of getting useful help increase exponentially if you provide real code. Here are the arguments to `Win32::Process::Create`:

**`$iflags`:** flag: inherit calling processes handles or not

Now, I am not sure if you are trying to capture the `STDOUT` of the second process or if you are trying to have its `STDOUT` output show up in the same console as the parent.

If the latter, then the following scripts illustrate one way of doing that:

#### parent.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32;
use Win32::Process;

$| = 1;

my $p;

print "Starting child process ... \n";

Win32::Process::Create(
    $p,
    'c:/opt/perl/bin/perl.exe',
    'perl hello.pl',
    1,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    '.',
) or die Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );

print "Waiting three seconds before killing 'hello.pl'\n";

for (1 .. 3) {
    print;
    sleep 1;
}
$p->Kill(0)
    or die "Cannot kill '$p'";
```

#### hello.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$| = 1;

print "Hello World\n";
print "Sleeping 1000 seconds\n";

for (1 .. 1000) {
    sleep 1;
    print '.';
}
```

#### Output:

```
Starting child process ...
Waiting three seconds before killing 'hello.pl'
1Hello World
Sleeping 1000 seconds
2.3.
```

Now, **I am still not sure why you are using `Win32::Process`**. Unless there is a specific reason to tie your script to `Win32`, I would recommend using standard Perl facilities. For example, read [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [`perldoc perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) (see esp. [*Using open for IPC*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC)).

Explain your question better to get answers that address your particular situation rather than generalities.

Comment: If I create the process through the system command, I was not able to find any method to terminate the process on win32. On Linux I just used system("kill -9 -$$") to kill the perl script and all it's children but couldn't find anything so simple on Windows

Comment: http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html All kidding aside, I find `system("kill -9 -$$")` suspect. `fork` works on Windows: `fork` your children, save their `pid`s and `wait` on them or `kill` them as you see fit. I prefer http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel::ForkManager

Comment: Tried that and would love to do that - however, if I fork() and then call my child script through exec or system, the PID of the exec'd process is different from the PID returned by fork.

Comment: Watch out with forking on Windows. It's fine for a couple of processes, but I've had lots of problems with Windows handling hundreds of them from the same process.

Comment: @brian d foy I never gone above a few dozen (and that in only one program). Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Naseer if you have questions about IPC in Perl, you should formulate a separate question and post it. Your specific question has been answered: Set the `iflags` argument to `Win32::Process::Create`.

Comment: @Sinan, Thanks for your detailed replies, I was using the Kill command in Win32 Process anyway. I had tried setting the $iflags, but specifying "perl hello.pl" (or using -w as mentioned in my answer) seems to be doing the trick. 

I did try open but it didn't work either and hence this method.

I am not a perl programmer - this script is just a quick hack to get something done at work and it needed perl - hence the bad practices.

Comment: @Naseer Thank you for accepting my answer. However, I had forgotten about the pseudo-processes `fork` launches on Windows. So, you are right, `fork` + `exec` + `kill` would not work. I am glad `Win32::Process` worked for you. So, I guess the answer to your question was that the `$cmdline` parameter has to include the name of the executable you are running + the command line arguments. I don't think you can rely on `-w` making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Using -w before $filepath fixed it ! Still need an explanation though.